# display string on client side by fetching data from server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to display a string on the client-side by fetching the result from serverside but for some reason, it is not displaying the fetched data. When I console log the variable straight on the js file the server successfully prints the string. The program is not exporting the variable to the client-side to display it. I can't figure out where I went wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const {
  callName
} = require("pathJs");

router.route("PathRoute").get(async(req, res) => {
  const Result = await callName();
  return res.json(Result);
});


module.exports = router;
```

```js
function name() {
  const liner = "this works"
  console.log(liner)
  //updated
  return liner;

}

async function callName() {
  const data1 = await name()
  return data1;

}

callName()
```

```html
<p id="insertHere" style="color: white;"></p>


<script>
  async function caller() {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/PATH`)
      .then((res) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(res.json())
          }, 1000)
        })

      }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = response.liner

        }

      )
  }
</script>
```

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const routePath = require("./routePath");
const {
  response
} = require("express");
require("dotenv").config({
  debug: process.env.DEBUG
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api", routePath);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port: http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: `function name() {` logs a value but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: do I have to return ```liner``` in function ```name```. @Quentin

Comment: i returned every data in function name below that function.@Quentin

Comment: `name` has no `return` statement so it returns `undefined`. `callName` does have a `return` statement, it returns the return value of `name` … which is `undefined` so `callName` returns (because it is an `async` function) a promise that resolves to `undefined`. If you want to return the value of `liner` then you have to return it.

Comment: I returned ```liner``` in my name function but the string is still not displayed on the client-side. @Quentin

Comment: Why is `callName` async and why do you await `name`?

Comment: to wait for my promise.@jabaa

Comment: "still not displayed on the client-side" — Does the `console.log` you have before the assignment to `innerHTML` show you anything?

Comment: no it doesn't. @Quentin

Comment: @anon20010813 — Not even `undefined`? Any error messages in the console? Maybe something about CORS?

Comment: nope nothing at all@Quentin

Comment: There is no promise in `name()`.

Comment: I have another promise code I haven't included in my function. It is not relevant to displaying my string.@jabaa

Comment: First you should localize your problem. Is it a client or server side problem? Then create a [mcve]. It looks like there is much unrelated code in your question. Use a network sniffer like Wireshark, tcpdump or your browser debug tools to analyze the response.

Comment: my fetch is not responding so I added my reduced server-side, my route, and my main js file minified to the fullest. all the added code is potentially the root of my error. Did you read the code I added? cause all the things you have suggested till now don't have anything to do with a potential solution.@jabaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no export in `pathJs` and you want `name()` to return an object containing `liner`. You need

```
function name() {
  const liner = "this works"
  console.log(liner)
  //updated
  return {liner};

}

async function callName() {
  const data1 = await name()
  return data1;

}

callName()

module.exports = { callName };
```

The backend is probably crashing with `TypeError: callName is not a function` while handling the request and therefore doesn't send a response.

Comment: yes that was the main problem but I get ```liner``` not defined on client-side now.@jabaa

Comment: @anon20010813 Of course not. `liner` is a server side variable. How should it be known on client side? `callName` returns the string `"this works"`, nothing else.

Comment: exporting the specific variable won't work? @jabaa

Comment: @anon20010813 You should probably read [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) Server side code is evaluated on a server. Client side code is evaluated on a different computer. They don't share the same memory. If you want to share values you have to send them. You can't simply export a variable from server side to client side.

Comment: my main goal was to insert ```this works``` into innerHtml. on client-side. by receiving its response.@jabaa

Comment: On Stackoverflow you ask a specific question and get specific answers. Discussion, debugging and mutliple problems in one question doesn't work well with this platform. Questions starting with _"I'm trying to..."_ are usually to broad. I solved two of your problems. If you still have problems, localize and debug them and ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for all ther help. Just figured out how to insert it into my inner HTML too I returned liner like ```return {liner}``` and inserted it as```document.getElementById("insertHere").innerHTML = response.liner``` . Thanks for the cs vs ss explanation link. @jabba